# Failed to add the cluster permission of a user

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I tried to add user privileges to a cluster, but fail to add, received the following error message:

```
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "rancherauth.cattle.io": 
Post https://rancher-webhook.cattle-system.svc:443/v1/webhook/validation?timeout=10s:
dial tcp 10.43.48.11:443: connect: connection refused.
```

I searched elsewhere but got no answer.
Does anyone know the cause and the solution?

Comment: Does anyone know the cause and the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this issue deploying Rancher, found a workaround for now.
Error message by Rancher is not helpful.

All of cluster nodes are Rocky-Linux-8 with firewalld enabled, Checked firewalld logs for dropped packages and found out some requests are being dropped for port 6443 saying `kernel: STATE_INVALID_DROP`.

[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enable-firewalld-logging-for-denied-packets-on-linux/) is a great tutorial on firewalld logging

My workaround was to add all nodes to trusted-zone of firewalld, so that every single node in cluster trusts each other.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-source=192.168.0.0/16
systemctl restart firewalld
systemctl restart docker
```

You may also simply stop and disable firewalld as recommended by Rancher

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl restart docker
```